Python - Select a complex subset of columns from a np.array
I want have an array X, and I want to select, for example, the 1st, 5th, 7th, and all of the last 1000 columns (non-overlapping). I know I can get the 1st, 5th, 7th columns using X[:, [0,4,6]] and the last 1000 columns by X[:, -1000:]. But is there a quick and easy way to select them all together using one line/object?

I thought something like X[:,[0,4,6,-1000:]] would work but it didn't

You can use np.r_:
X[:, np.r_[[0,4,6],-1000:0]]

Example with a (5, 20) array selecting 0,4,6 and the last 10:
X = np.arange(100).reshape(-1, 20)
X[:, np.r_[[0,4,6],-10:0]]

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
#        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
#        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]])

Intermediate:
np.r_[[0,4,6],-10:0]
# array([  0,   4,   6, -10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1])

Note that you should ensure that the slices are not overlapping, else you would have duplicated columns.

X : list = [x for x in range(1,2001)]
elements : list = [X[i] for i in [0,4,6]] + X[1000:]

